# How to forward port after tunneling

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

Today I have read this question and answer ([How does reverse SSH tunneling work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46235/how-does-reverse-ssh-tunneling-work)). I tried it out and it worked perfectly however I want to know one thing. Say I have a web server running on port 8000 and I forward that port to my receiving server. How do I then forward the port the receiving server gets to others on the network.

E.g.:

I have a Server 1(Ubuntu Server running with full port forwarding and no firewall). I have another server 2 (running WITH a firewall and without port forwarding). I use SSH tunnelling to put my web server onto Server 1 from server 2. How can I let clients who can connect to server 1 connect to the tunnelled service from server 2 via server 1

Client 1 Cannot Connect to Server 2 but can connect to server 1.

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/168145/how-to-use-ssh-tunneling/

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly what you are asking, but I suspect that you are interested in the [`ssh -g` flag](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh&sektion=1), which "Allows remote hosts to connect to local forwarded ports."