# SSH port forwarding to Android x11

Tags: ssh

This works

```
ssh -i -Y -v "key.pem" ubuntu@ec2-52-14-84-246.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

This is port forwarding from another SO question

```
ssh -L 2222:localhost:8888 -N -o GatewayPorts=yes hostname-of-M
```

I'm told I need to forward from remote 6001 to localhost 6000. How do I combine the two commands? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> ssh -i -Y -v "key.pem" ubuntu@ec2-52-14-84-246.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
> ```

This can't work. You mixed up arguments. It should be `... -i "key.pem"-Y -v ...`. It simply does X11 forwarding.

> ```
> ssh -L 2222:localhost:8888 -N -o GatewayPorts=yes hostname-of-M
> ```

This forwards [remote port 8888 to local port 2222](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/115906/121504). You just need to replace the port numbers:

```
ssh -L 6000:localhost:6001 -i "key.pem" -Y ubuntu@ec2-52-14-84-246.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

Nothing more, nothing less.