# Is it possible to forbid a specific user from executing files on /usr/bin without changing all files permission to 750?

Tags: permissions, path, chmod

I understand the concept of managing permissions on Linux with `chmod` using the first digit as the **user**, the second as the **group** and the third as **other users** as described on [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/183999/103357) in [Understanding UNIX permissions and file types](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183994/understanding-unix-permissions-and-file-types/183999#183999).

Let's say I have a Linux system with 5 users: `admin`, `usera`, `userb`, `userc` and `guest`. By default, the users `usera`, `userb` and `userc` will have execution permission on all files inside `/usr/bin`, so these users can use the command line of the system executing the files in there as those files have 75**5** permission. So far it's completely ok. However, I'd like to forbid the user `guest` from executing files on the folder `/usr/bin`, I know I could achieve that by changing the permission of all files inside this folder to something like 750 with `chmod`, but if I do that I'll mess up the permissions of the users `usera`, `userb` and `userc` because they will be also forbidden to execute files.

On my computer, all the files in `/usr/bin` belong to the group `root`, so I know I could create a `newgroup`, change the group of all those files to it and add `usera`, `userb` and `userc` to `newgroup`. But doing that sounds like way too much modification on the system's default settings. Does anyone know a smarter way of solving this problem?

How can I forbid a single user from using the command line (or executing any file on `PATH`) without an overcomplicated solution that requires changing the permissions of too many files?

Comment: Use group permissions and have that user not be in that group

Comment: @planetmaker no! You'll either break the entire system or else break distribution upgrades.

Comment: That implies user `guest` won't even have a shell to start, because `/usr/bin` and `/bin` are identical in many modern distros. (My gut feeling would be to try and put them in a chroot jail; it's possible that `systemd` even gives you nice automatisms for that, like it does for services.)

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz You're right but for my case of use, it works fine... I'm giving ssh access to the user `guest` just so he can [port forward](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/115906/103357) the system to have access to specific web applications.  Even with the terminal dead for running the shell, applications running on ports by other users on the system will still work fine after port forwarding.

Comment: I'd implement this with a PAM module that does a bind mount of `/var/empty` over `/usr/bin` in a private filesystem namespace during login for the relevant user. Why do something that modifies the filesystem for everyone, when you can modify the filesystem only for the one user?

Comment: See https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-mount-namespaces/index.html discussing a (different) private-namespace PAM module's implementation.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy seems to have become something ubiquitous: https://manpages.debian.org/stable/libpam-modules/pam_namespace.8.en.html . Are you over with this? I might write an alternate answer

Comment: My instincts would be to set the user's login shell to something very restricted - and then make sure that the SSH settings don't allow "ssh hostname ls /" to bypass that.  Don't know off the top of my head if that's actually possible and if so what the exact sshd_config settings would be.

Comment: Just a heads up, but permissions are defined with 4 octal digits, not 3. You might be thinking that all your files are 755, but I have many that are 4755, 2755, 6755, etc. 750 is the same as 0750, so by changing them all to 750, you might be breaking quite a few executables (like sudo) by clearing their suid, sgid, and sticky bits.

Comment: @A.B, by all means do write it up yourself.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy on 2nd thought, I drop this. This would go far from the initial question. Just to tell you that what you wrote works fine with pam_namespace. Documentation isn't that great but present ([`man pam_namespace`](https://manpages.debian.org/libpam-modules/pam_namespace.8) + [`man namespace.conf`](https://manpages.debian.org/libpam-modules/namespace.conf.5))

Comment: @JoL Good Point. Just as a curiosity, would you know a way of changing the permission of the last three octal digits of files while keeping the first octal as it is? Instead of just replacing it with 0?

Comment: @RafaelMuynarsk, you can always specify `chmod o= ...files...` to clear only the  "other" field and leave u/g and the other bits like temp and set[ug]id alone. But to be very, very clear, doing that with `/usr/bin` is a *horrible* idea. I really do recommend the bind-mount approach to leave the rest of the system alone while changing a single user's view of it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use ACLs to remove the permissions. In this case, you don't need to modify the permissions of all the executables; just remove the execute permission from `/usr/bin/` to disallow traversal of that directory and therefore access of any files within.

```
setfacl -m u:guest:r /usr/bin
```

This sets the permissions of `u`ser `guest` to just `r`ead for the directory `/usr/bin`, so they can `ls` that directory but not access anything within.

You could also just remove all permissions:

```
setfacl -m u:guest:- /usr/bin
```

Comment: This will potentially break all distribution upgrades. It's a really bad idea.

Comment: why? from the command above only the user `guest` would be affected or am I missing something?

Comment: @roaima: Explain please.

Comment: If nothing else, it'll break when whatever your OS's equivalent to the `filesystem` package is gets reinstalled and tries to reassert the original permissions.

Comment: @Charles I don't that that checks ACLs.

Comment: I'd say that the directory and its permission are/were set, while the system was installed. So neither would the solution break, nor would the solution break anything else.

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to do? Forbidding use of the system's standard commands to some user is just incivil behavior in the extreme... commands that could put the system in jeopardy are far in between, and have been carefully vetted for security. The permissions on files should stop most attempts at mischief.

- Consider giving them a restricted shell (check the manuals, it is probably named something like `rbash`; careful though, `rsh` is a different kind of animal!). They cage the user rather effectively (but watch out, it *is* possible to break out!)
- If this is a pseudo-user in charge of owning some service, the common way out is to give the "user" a shell that does nothing, like `/bin/true` (check your system's manual for any recommendations in this line, there might be a special program for this; if `/bin/true` is a shell script *don't use it for this*). That way, if somebody manages to log in to that account, their session finishes immediately.
- Create a `chroot`for them (again, there are ways to break out), or use Linux' containers of BSD's jails to confine them, and just expose exactly what you want them to see. Most control, but messy to set up and keep up to date.

Comment: Forbidding use of the system's standard commands to users is not uncivil behavior, everything depends on the context of how it's being used, even the act of deleting a user could be seen as uncivil behavior if used by the wrong person. But as I wrote in the comments of my question, I'm giving ssh access to the user guest just so he can port forward the system to have access to specific web applications. A "caged" shell wouldn't be the ideal solution to my case because it'd still allow the user to use RAM memory and CPU power with scripts. But thanks for bringing a different perspective.

Comment: @RafaelMuynarsk if you want to limit the user to port forwarding and nothing else, you may want an SSH "Forced Command", see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48129/how-to-create-a-restricted-ssh-user-for-port-forwarding) and/or google for "ssh forced command" (you may not even need a separate user!)

Comment: @Josh That's actually exactly what I needed. I haven't thought I could create these restrictions directly on my SSH configuration. Thanks!

Comment: Sure thing! Yeah I didn't know about forced commands for years, they're an amazing feature (especially for running specific commands remotely as root or other privileged users)