# scp to local from a remote server that ssh's to another remote server

Tags: linux, ssh, scp, webserver

I currently have a file on serverB that I would like to transfer to my local computer. To get to serverB I first ssh to serverA then ssh to serverB.
(e.g. ssh @serverA then inside serverA -> ssh @serverB)

Not sure what would be the best way to do this with scp?

Comment: scp uses the same connection and authentication methods as ssh. If you can't log on to serverB directly, you need to copy the file in two steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ProxyJump` option in `~/.ssh/config`. From `man ssh`:

> **-J destination**
>
> Connect to the target host by first making a **ssh** connection to the jump host described by destination and then
> establishing a TCP forwarding to the ultimate destination from there.
> Multiple jump hops may be specified separated by comma characters.
> This is a shortcut to specify a **ProxyJump** configuration directive.
> Note that configuration directives supplied on the command-line
> generally apply to the destination host and not any specified jump
> hosts. Use ~/.ssh/config to specify configuration for jump hosts.

For example, your `~/.ssh/config` may look like this:

```
Host serverA
Port 22

Host serverB
Port 22
ProxyJump serverA
```

This will tell `ssh` to always connect to serverB **via** serverA, and it will do this for both normal `ssh` and for `scp`. In other words, you can type `ssh serverB` or `scp serverB:big_file.txt .` and it will know to route through ServerA. (You will, however, need a local copy of the key needed for serverB if you are using public key authentication.)

This is often referred to has "jump host" in `ssh`. A related config option in `~/.ssh/config` is `ProxyCommand`.

Comment: `scp` doesn't have the `-J` option, but you can use its `-o` option to specify a ProxyJump directly on the command line (something like `scp -o "ProxyJump serverA" localfile serverB:remotefile`).

Comment: @GordonDavisson - actually, in Ubuntu 20.04, `scp` **does** have a `-J` option. Maybe this was a recent addition.

Comment: Looks like it was added to `scp` in... OpenSSH v8.0? Yikes, I'm way more out of date than I realized! (v8.4 is current)

Comment: Thanks! I tired this and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

one way is [bitinerant](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/630669/60575) solution and there are other ways.

1. if you need more than one time, it is better use `sshfs` on *serverA* and `scp from local to serverA`
2. if you need only one time, you could use `ssh tunnel`
   please follow [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115897/whats-ssh-port-forwarding-and-whats-the-difference-between-ssh-local-and-remot) for tunneling and for *sshfs*

```
ssh to serverA
sshfs user@serverB:/foldertomount/ ~/mountpoint
scp ~/mountpoint/desiredFile LocalIP:/Path/
```