# What is ssh -L 123:farawayhost:456 remotehost?

Tags: ssh

Came from this question: [What's ssh port forwarding and what's the difference between ssh local and remote port forwarding](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115897/whats-ssh-port-forwarding-and-whats-the-difference-between-ssh-local-and-remot), I am confused about this usage:

`ssh -L 123:farawayhost:456 remotehost`

> `ssh -L sourcePort:forwardToHost:onPort connectToHost` means:
> connect with ssh to `connectToHost`, and forward all connection
> attempts to the **local** `sourcePort` to port `onPort` on the machine
> called `forwardToHost`, which can be reached from the `connectToHost`
> machine.

What does "..., which **can be reached** from the `connectToHost` machine." mean exactly?

If I understand correctly, `ssh -L 123:localhost:456 remotehost` is a specific case for the above command, where both `farawayhost` and `remotehost` are on the same machine.

So when `farawayhost` is and `remotehost` are not on the same machine， how does it work? Does it mean that I need to log into `remotehost` first and then `farawayhost` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why I got confused at first, maybe because the original answer is not clear enough, but then I figured that out all of a sudden.

Suppose I have 2 machine, whose public ip are `1.2.3.4` and `2.3.4.5`.

The usage would be: `ssh -L 10283:1.2.3.4:8000 username@2.3.4.5 -N` , it will prompt a newline, requring a password of `username` on `2.3.4.5`.

[image]

when successfully authenticated, `ssh` won't log you in because `-N` is specified, but the connection has been made. So any data send to **local** port `10283` will firstly be sent to `2.3.4.5` via `ssh` (port `22`), then `2.3.4.5` will send the data to `1.2.3.4` on port `8000.`

Now let me create a html file by `echo hello > index.html` and run a http server on `1.2.3.4` with `python -m http.server`.

And then I type `localhost:10283` on my local PC.

Local PC:

[image]

On `1.2.3.4`:

[image]