# "Reverse" an SSH connection from destination to target

Tags: ssh, networking, firewall, subnets

I have two machines A and B which are in different subnets, both behind separate firewalls. Machine A can see B, but B cannot see A. I have a user account (non-root) on both machines, I can SSH B from A, and *I would like to be able to SSH A from B instead*, but that cannot be done directly.

I have used tunnelling to hop through intermediate servers with SSH, but what I am asking is different here, and I don't know what it would be called. Is there a way to open a connection from A to B, which could in turn be used "in reverse" from machine B to run commands on A?

Comment: This looks like what you're after: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46235 . Basically you want the `-R` option of forwarding (exposing a port on the dialling machine to the remote host)

Comment: Reading through the answers now, but looks like it does :) Thanks a lot @zefixlluja! Feel free to vote to close as duplicate. I will support the vote once I finish reading if that answers my question, or clarify otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is yes you can, the how is:

```
machine-A$ ssh -R 127.0.0.1:2222:127.0.0.1:22 [ip__or_name_of_B]
```

Then on `B` you can `ssh` to `A` with:

```
machine-B$ ssh -p2222 127.0.0.1
```

This says the following:

- On `A` create a tunnel on the remote side (`-R`), such that any traffic that goes to localhost (`127.0.0.1`) on port `2222` should come back through the tunnel and be sent to localhost (`127.0.0.1` now on the local side) port `22`
- The `B` command simply says, `ssh` to localhost port `2222` which is the entrance to the tunnel.

Comment: thanks to you i understand with a simple command