# SSH tunnel between 2 machines that can only ssh to a 3rd machine, but not directly to one another

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

There are 3 machines in my setup:

```
M1     M2     M3
```

- I need to open an SSH shell on M1 controlling M3.
- Both M1 and M3 are behind different firewalls, and can't reach one another directly.
- Both M1 and M3 *can* reach (and connect via ssh) to M2. But not the other way around - M2 can't reach M1 or M3.

Can I use M2 to create a tunnel from M1 to M3?

```
M1 --> M2 <-- M3
 \____________^
```

Comment: Does [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46235/how-does-reverse-ssh-tunneling-work) help (reverse `ssh` tunnel might be what you're looking for)?

Comment: Right, you'd need to have the reverse tunnel set up from M3 to M2 (as per the answer from @Sagar), and then you could use the usual tricks of proxy jumping (albeit with the modified port for the last step)

Comment: Explore socks proxy. This way you will get smooth vpn like experience (better than port forwarding)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from M3

```
ssh -R localhost:2602:localhost:22 user@M2
```

from M1

```
ssh -L localhost:2602:localhost:2602 user@M2
```

Now you can connect directly to M3 from M1 (here localhost actually means M3)

```
ssh user@localhost -p 2602
```

Comment: btw you can also do the socks proxy instead of port forwarding and that will let you connect to M3 from M1 like ssh user@M3  instead of user@localhost and then exclusively mentioning port number

Comment: This worked! And I didn't need the first line ("from M1")

Comment: Oh yeah right. Haha my bad. I forgot that.

Answer (score 1):

I use `-J` (I remember it as "Jump") to do this.

M1 -> M3 (via M2):

```
ssh -J M2 M3
```

`scp` also supports something similar:

```
scp --ProxyJump=M2 localfile M3:remotefile
```

---

I think it's easiest to explain with IPs:

```
M1 = 192.168.1.100
M2 = 192.168.1.101 & 10.10.1.200
M3 = 10.10.1.201
```

M1 can't access `10.10.1.x` so it has to go through M2 which accesses both networks.  Let's say you also have different users on each machine for extra complexity.  To SSH from M1 to M3:

```
m1user@192.168.1.100: ~ $ ssh -J m2user@192.168.1.101 m3user@10.10.1.201
```

or to get `remotefile` from M3 onto M1:

```
scp --ProxyJump=m2user@192.168.1.101 m3user@10.10.1.201:remotefile localfile
```

Comment: Does this work if M3 and M1 both block incoming connections from M2 (as per OP requirements)?  The proxy jump only works if you can make the connection from the intermediary to the destination, no?

Comment: Ah, no.  I didn't notice that.  This is the same as `ssh`ing into M2, then `ssh`ing from M2 to M3.  If M2 can't `ssh` into M3, this doesn't work.