# SSH Forwarding between client and two servers

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ssh-tunneling

I'm trying to figure out how to set up a shh tunnel between client and two servers. I need client to connect to ServerB via ServerA.

These are the facts:

- Client can connect to ServerA (via public IP).
- Client cannot connect to ServerB.
- ServerA cannot connect to ServerB. (Server is remotely separated from
  ServerA and behind NAT).
- ServerB can connect to ServerA (via public IP).
- Neither ServerA or ServerB can connect to host. (Client does not have
  a public IP).

What would be the ssh command(s) to set it up exactly?

Comment: You'll either need to allow inbound traffic to server B from server A, or build a reverse tunnel (where server B starts the connection to A and keeps it open).

Comment: @Panki Thanks for the feedback Panki. I'm actually having issue with figuring out the ssh command(s) I would need to use to create such a tunnel. You might help me with that?

Comment: As I understand it, it is not possible with a single command. You'll have to 1) build a reverse tunnel from B to A b) Connect to A from client and use the tunnel. [This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46235/how-does-reverse-ssh-tunneling-work) is a good starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd connect client to server A, server B to server A, and tunnel via server A.

On client:

`ssh -L 2200:127.0.0.1:2200 user@serverA`

On server B:

`ssh -R 2200:127.0.0.1:22 user@serverA`

Then to SSH from client to server B, you'd simply run (from the client):

`ssh -P 2200 user@serverB`

Comment: Thanks Ron. I actually already figured it out, however. At least thanks to your feedback I know it's the right way how to do it. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I figured it out.

On Client: 
`ssh -A user@ServerB`

On ServerB 
`ssh -N -R 44444:localhost:22 user@ServerA -p 2222`

*`-p 2222` in my case SSH server is not listening on the default port `22`*

On Client: 
`ssh user@localhost -p 44444`