# Creating a Linux distribution that only runs one application

Tags: linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I build a custom distribution for running a simple web browser?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17779/how-can-i-build-a-custom-distribution-for-running-a-simple-web-browser)

Is it possible to create a Linux distribution that only runs one application? For example, I want it to just run a browser, and not support any other applications. How can I do that?

Comment: Sounds like the [GNU/LINUX Kiosk Project](http://kiosk.mozdev.org/) description.

Comment: You're asking for Google's Chrome OS!

Comment: Yes something like this but I want my own browser :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user has "root" access, she'll always find a way to run anything she wants. On the other hand, ifthe user doesn't have root access, you can try to limit her access to one application.

[Lshell](http://lshell.ghantoos.org/) is a restrictive shell that allows you to do this at the shell level. If you have a graphical environment, it's even easier. Put only one giant button in the screen :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure it's *possible*, but probably more work than you want.  I suppose you'd have to look into the bootscripts.  It might be easier to create a user, change permissions on the rest of the drive to lock him out (except necessary programs and libraries), give him an autologin gnome/kde session, set the `novtswitch` option in xorg.conf, and change his login script to launch the browser/whatever.

Answer (score 0):

It is obviously possible. The simplest way I can think of is that each time the user is logged on , he is chrooted to a restricted shell, that has only one command, your application. Of course, this is easier said than done.